# Giving an input inside a batch file which replaces the input with a specific string from a other file

Tags: batch-file, replace

Basically I just want to code a batch script that ask me for a input after running it, hitting enter after the text the Text that I wrote will replace it with the old text in a mentioned lined in the sc. I am using windows11 and never tried smth like this, it would be nice if someone can show me how to do it and explain the commands too so that I won't ask again for stuff like this. This is my current code, I just want to add a option 3 which asks for a input and replaces my input in a other file at a specific string or behind a specific words (max_items: [my input] in my case).

```
@echo off
title Changing Configs..
color B
:main
echo 1 = grind time
echo 2 = trade time
set /p ibo=
if %ibo% == 1 goto grind
if %ibo% == 2 goto trade
:grind
ren "config.yml" "trading"
ren "grinding" "config.yml"
exit

:trade
ren "config.yml" "grinding"
ren "trading" "config.yml"
exit
```

Comment: What you need to do is to stop (ab)using the wrong, _(`set`)_, command, to perform a task which is designed for the `choice` utility. Please use the search facility at the top of the page, together with the Command Prompt output from `choice /?` to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: @Compo Thx for your hint, I will inform myself about the command and rewrite it again with `choice` also do you have an Idea how I can replace a single string with a input that I give manually without editing the batch script everytime?

Comment: There are [hundreds](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+find+and+replace) and [thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+edit+file) of examples on this site how to do it. Pick your choice (and come back and edit your question when you can't quite get it to work)